# ValidateModel or tools in c++ and proto problems

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, c++, cp-sat

I'm trying to validate my model, this is the relevant part of my code:

```
    cp_model.Maximize(LinearExpr::Sum(obj_final));

    SatHelper::ValidateModel(cp_model);
    //solve
    Model model;
    //
    // Sets a time limit of 10 seconds.

    SatParameters parameters;
    parameters.set_max_time_in_seconds(10.0);
    model.Add(NewSatParameters(parameters));

    // Solve.

    const CpSolverResponse response = SolveCpModel(cp_model.Build(), &model);
    LOG(INFO) << CpSolverResponseStats(response);

    if (response.status() == CpSolverStatus::FEASIBLE) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nbTasks; ++j)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "  x = " << SolutionIntegerValue(response, starts[j]);
        }}
```

For some reason my model is invalid and I want to validate it to get detailed information about it. But I get this error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘operations_research::sat::SatHelper::ValidateModel(operations_research::sat::Model&)’
     SatHelper::ValidateModel(model);
```

and suggests:

```
note: candidate: static std::__cxx11::string operations_research::sat::SatHelper::ValidateModel(const operations_research::sat::CpModelProto&)
```

So, what is a `CpModelProto`? I read the documentation but it is hard to understand. I've seen most of the c++ examples of or-tools and I haven't found any `CpModelProto` in the solving part. And finally, what can I do to validate my model and check where the problem is?

Additionally, if someone can give me a nice explanation of how to print/solve and setting parameters, it will be nice, because the examples use FLAGS and LOG and they are confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`CpModelProto` is a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) representation of your model in ortools.

You create it by using the `CpModelBuilder` class (your `cp_model`), and calling its `Build()` method, the [SolveCpModel](https://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_sat/namespaceoperations__research_1_1sat.html#a9d67b9c66f1cb9c1dcc3415cd5af11bf) function that you are using actually also takes a `CpModelProto` as its first argument.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but its no printing anything. i used: std::cout << SatHelper::ValidateModel(cp_model.Build()) << std::endl; and just print coeffs:  -1 on cmd. This is the info that the method drops?

Comment: If you parse C++ command line arguments using the Google gflags code, you can try with -vmodule=cp_model_checker=2. It should display more information